# Is there a way to forward individual voicemails on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, voicemail

I would like to send a voicemail I received to someone else for them to be able to listen to the exact same audio.

Is there a way to forward an individual voicemail to someone else, whether by email or some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully someone else can provide an easier answer or an app that automates this, but the method I've found so far only works for jailbroken phones:

1. Use iFile or some other file manager to access .amr files that are stored in `/var/mobile/Library/Voicemail`. The files are numbered sequentially and `voicemail.db` looks like its used to organize them.
2. Try to locate the correct .amr using timestamp.
3. Use file manager to email .amr file to myself or someone else.

A sidenote is that doing this I was able to find some orphaned .amr files that seemed to not have been completely deleted (.amr files are still stored when deleted until they are cleared from Deleted Messages). I was able to safely delete these old voicemails (over a year old, probably persisting from backups) from the folder.