# Backup, share, or save iPhone voicemail messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, voicemail

Is there a way to export, save, share, or e-mail voicemail (not Voice Memos) from the iPhone?

I am guessing there are some under-the-hood ways to get at the files [once you sync to a desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400718/how-can-i-backup-sort-and-listen-to-all-of-my-iphone-voice-message-on-my-macbo), but is there any way to do it straight from the iPhone?

I have seen [this response](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/is-there-a-way-to-forward-individual-voicemails-on-the-iphone) for jailbroken phones.

How can I backup and archive my iOS voicemail messages?

Comment: Does the solution need to be free or built-in to iOS? Is a computer-based alternative acceptable?

Comment: This is built into iOS 9: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are applications that can extract the voice messages from your phone but they cost money and required the phone be plugged in to the computer.

The simplest way is to connect your phone to your computer with a 3.5mm audio cable. Use a simple audio recording app, such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net), click record and play the voice message.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose recording to Audacity or GarageBand, etc is a reasonable option if there is no internal method.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Decipher Voice Mail](http://www.deciphertools.com) for a year or so and it saves all my iPhone voicemails as mp3 files on my computer. Great little program that enabled me to save my grandmother's voicemails after she passed away.

Comment: BIG thumbs up for this old reply - i had never heard of this mac app until now (2022), tried it and it works great. not only elts you export your iphone voicemails on your mac, the export is amazing and evev creates a web page for each contact with a text summary and a link to the audio files. AND is preserves the metadata (date/time/contact name (if any).contact number.

Answer (score 2):

I used a third party app called [**TouchCopy**](http://www.wideanglesoftware.com/touchcopy/index.php) to save my iPhone voicemail messages to my computer.

> TouchCopy allows you to play and copy Voice Mail messages you have received on your iPhone. To view all Voice Mails stored on your iPhone, click the Voice Mail button in TouchCopy.
>
> TouchCopy will copy messages from your iPhone if your iPhone supports Visual Voice Mail. These will be voice mails that are provided as part of the Visual Voice Mail data plan from your mobile service provider.

<sup>Source: [Copying iPhone Voice Mails with TouchCopy](https://www.wideanglesoftware.com/support/touchcopy/how-to-save-iphone-voicemails.php)</sup>

Note that the voice mails actually need to be stored on your iPhone rather than by the network operator for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Google Voice number that I just forward important voicemails to.

To do this in a typical voicemail system, you'd press 6 for more options, then 2 to forward it.

You can keep them in your Google account pretty much as long as you want, or you can simply download them at will.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Most people use [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) for this. It's an app from Ecamm:

http://www.ecamm.com

You plug the iPhone to the Mac, and it all shows up on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://VoicemailsForever.com It was really simple and took me just a few minutes to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more programs that let you export voicemails from your iPhone to your PC:

- [iMazing](http://imazing.com/features/transfer-voicemail-voice-memos-call-history-notes) (not free, and only allows you to export one voicemail in trial mode)
- [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/blog/transfer-voicemails-from-iphone-to-pc-mac-without-jailbreaking.htm) (not free, but allows you to export all voicemails in trial mode)
- [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/tutorials/how-to-access-voicemail-on-iphone) (not free, and does not let you export any voicemail in trial mode)

All three programs run on Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No - iOS versions up to and including iOS 9 do not allow you to forward, edit, share or otherwise push a voicemail that is stored on the device.

You'll need to avail yourself to a jailbreak mod (I don't recommend this) or a tool to read the files from the phone when it's paired with a computer. You can use USB or WiFi pairing and there are many choices of apps to grab the voicemail files but they depend on your choice of computer OS.

Lastly, contact your carrier - they might allow you to forward a message that's still on their servers or be able to assist you. Again - there are hundreds of carriers, so that's more a thing to research for your specific carrier or change carriers if you can find one to help with this function/feature.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has released a support document for how to save iOS Voicemail messages:

> #### Save and share Visual Voicemail messages on your iPhone
>
> Save your Visual Voicemail messages as notes or voice memos, and share them using Messages, Mail, or Airdrop.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205012

Apple's advice is to save the voicemail message via the Notes or Voice Memos app:

> - Go to Phone > Voicemail.
> - Tap the voicemail message that you'd like to save, then tap the share button.
> - Choose Notes or Voice Memos. Then save your voicemail message. Or choose Messages, Mail, or AirDrop, then type and send your message with the attached voicemail. You can also share the voicemail by tapping an AirDrop contact.

Comment: true, but apple solution is almost worthless - does not preserve ANy meta data so you get a file called voicemail-12345... no date, not contact number

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iOS [Screen Recording](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207935) feature to record the Visual Voicemail playback within the iOS Phone app.

This video recording will be saved to your iCloud Photos Library. You can then adjust the Date & Time on the video so that it appears in your library exactly when the Voicemail was actually recorded.

This technique also saves the Visual Voicemail transcription of the Voicemail message, which in nice to have as a preview of the audio when scrolling through your Photo Library.

---

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Connect your device to iTunes using USB or Wi-Fi, select the device, then the Music tab and check the Voice Memos option, then sync the device.

Comment: I was wondering about voice mail from incoming calls, not the memos recorded with the Voice Memos app...

Answer (score -1):

Have Siri call your voicemail for you... Follow the voicemenu prompts....ez