# How can I copy all of my iPhone Voice Message on my MacBook?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, voice-memo

I have many recordings of birds as Voice Memos on my iPhone 6 with iOS 12.4.5 and I am trying to synch to my new MacBook macOS 10.15.6 using iTunes (which is now called Music?)

If I connect my iPhone to my new laptop then click the iPhone icon in Music it shows me an alphabetical list of *about half or less* of the Voice Memos that are on my phone. The list is alphabetical so I can't check the most recent recording date.

I have synched, but when I disconnect my phone the list disappears and I can not find Voice Memos on my laptop anywhere.

If I look on my hard drive under Music I don't see anything useful.

**Question:** How can I copy all of my iPhone Voice Message on my MacBook?

**note:** I don't use my phone for music, movies, TV shows, podcasts or audio books. I just want to get the voice memos as audio files into a folder on my laptop.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's always annoyed me that you can't even set sync preferences on a phone unless it is *connected* Maybe that is just me. But I got this app in a bundle called iMazing that *reliably* backs up my iPhone to my Mac and allows me to extract pretty much everything in the backup, including voicemail and voice memos. Most of the time I really hate Apple's sync/backup interface to iOS devices. iMazing (no relation just a happy customer) makes me actually *like* the process now. Recommended if you can't find another solution.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks for the info! I'm fairly app-shy (i.e. have none save for what Apple puts there) but there's always a first time. So Apple doesn't actually make what I want to do possible?

Comment: It may just be a trick that I don't know. Which is why it is a "comment" and not an answer. Perhaps someone else knows a different trick. But until then iMazing is free for a couple of weeks, I believe.